# Pagination error with angular table material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a screen where I have a table component of the angular material (mat-table), in it I have a column that has a button to open a modal, when opening this modal, I already pass an object in the data, then inside this modal I I have another component that is another table that will be filled with data coming from the data in the parent component, in this case the modal. Everything works, however when I go to change the page to see the next records I am presented with the following error:

**main.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')**

in the initial component where I have the button that opens the modal, I call it as follows:

```
 listaDados$: Observable<ILista[]> | null = null;

  listarGeral(elemento: string) {
    this.listarTodas(elemento);
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(Acompanhamento, {
      width: 'auto',
      data: {
        ordem: elemento,
        lista: this.listaDados$
      }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result) {
        this.compartilhaService.gravarOsImprodutiva(result)
          .subscribe(() => this.msgAlert.emit('Gerada com sucesso'));
      }
    });
  }


  listarTodas(os: string) {
    this.listaDados$ = this.compartilhaService.listar(os, '', 5, 1).pipe(
      catchError(() => {
        return of([]);
      })
    );
  }
```

Already with open modal I get the data like this:

```
 numeroOs: Observable<string> | null = null;

constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AcompanhamentoModal>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: Observable<object>,
  ) { }

  <app-acompa-lista-modal *ngIf="data['lista'] | async as  lista" [lista]="lista" [numeroOs]="data['ordem']"></app-acompa-lista-modal>
```

And finally, in the table component that is called inside the modal , I get it like this:

```
@Input() lista: ILista[] = [];
@Input() numeroOs: string;
totalRows = 0;
pageSize = 5;
currentPage = 0;
pageSizeOptions: number[] = [5, 10, 25, 50];
showFirstLastButtons: true;

 ngOnInit() {
    this.listaTabela();
  }

 listaTabela() {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ILista>(this.lista['lista']);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
      this.paginator.length = this.listaImprodutiva['totalElemento'];
    });

  }

 pageChanged(event: PageEvent) {
    this.pageSize = event.pageSize;
    this.currentPage = event.pageIndex;
      this.listaTabelaInicial(this.numeroOs, '', this.pageSize, this.currentPage + 1);
  }

listaTabelaInicial(dado: string, busca: string = '', limite: number, pagina: number) {
    if (busca === 'sim') {
      busca = 'true';
    } else if (busca === 'nao' || busca === 'não') {
      busca = 'false';
    }
    this.serviceCompartilhado.listagem(dado, busca, limite, pagina).subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        this.dataSource.data = res['lista'];
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.paginator.pageIndex = this.currentPage;
          this.paginator.length = res.totalElemento;
        });
      });
  }
```

Below the angular material paginator, how I use it

```
 <mat-paginator #paginator [length]="totalRows" [pageIndex]="currentPage" [pageSize]="pageSize" [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions" [showFirstLastButtons]="[showFirstLastButtons]" (page)="pageChanged($event)" aria-label="Select page">
</mat-paginator>
```

When I open the modal, the initial data already fills the table without errors, so let's say I have a total of 20 records in the database, in the table I do the pagination, initially showing 5 in 5, so I've already seen the first 5 records, when I'm going to move on to the next page, which calls the pageChanged(event: PageEvent) method, it works, but it keeps showing an error in the console.

[image]